# how to remove content border in Modal Window

Tags: jquery, css

does anyone know how to remove border of the content in the Modal Window?

Here is the picture, as you can see, for the first image+font, there's a orange border (Todo).

[image]

My Sample Modal Window code is here [Modal Window](http://jsfiddle.net/bfwUh/1/)

This is my code for css

```
table.ui-widget-content {
background: #ffffff url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
color: #222222;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
border: #aaaaaa double 1px;
-moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 10px;
box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 10px;
z-index: 180;
}
```

As you can see, when you click on the HOME text, it will show a modal window, inside the modal window i did put an image and word, just wonder by default why there's a orange color border on the image + font. How can I remove it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a:focus{
   outline:none;
}
```

I hope this code is help you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
.ui-widget-content{
   border:none !important;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bfwUh/2/)

Comment: the border still visible..I think your code is to remove the modal window border not inside the modal window border..I want to remove the orange border as you can see on the picture provided. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you using Chrome. I think it is visible when you use the tab key. you can disable using the following code:

```css
table.ui-widget-content {  
  outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already got the answer, just add `outline: none;` :)

```
.ui-widget-content a {
color: #222222;
outline: none;
```

}

and the border will go away...